# Why Can't I Drag IBAction from Storyboard to Swift File?

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, swift, interface-builder

I'm attempting to connect some buttons from a preferences view in my Swift OS X application.

Instead of putting all the IBActions and IBOutlets in my AppDelegate.swift file (seems messy, though I may be wrong), I'd like to simply have the actions and outlets interacting with another file. In this scenario I want to interface much of the userDefaults storage with the preferences window I create.

But whenever I attempt to drag a preference window button or anything else to the new swift file, it doesn't give me the same ability to drop the link and define the action/outlet.

If someone has any insight to this, or could help walk me through the process that would be fantastic. I have a bit of understanding of Xcode/cocoa and from what I've searched it may something to do with View Controllers, but I don't know where to go from here.

Thanks!
Tyler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With swift you could make a new file with an extension of the app delegate class and add the interface builder stuff there.

```
extension AppDelegate {
     //IB stuff here
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I would've never figured that out. I'm not sure how clean this is, should I be declaring this in a controller file with outlets I wish to manipulate? But regardless it works so thank you I appreciate it!

Comment: I believe you can create a new interface builder file and link it to a view controller class subclassing NSViewController, then put interface builder things within that view controller class. Most of what I know about this is coming the UIViewController class for iOS, but I believe the principles are the same :)